# Booting Ubuntu from USB security

Tags: usb, live-usb, security, antivirus

I personally run Linux Ubuntu 16.4/ 14.4. I have little experience with Microsoft, but I have to use a program for compiling logic software for work that's only supported in Windows. Not wanting to use a VM I bought a dell precision with Windows 7 pro.

Question: if I run Linux from a USB or dual boot can going online with my Linux side without virus protection on my Windows side cause security issues with my windows side.

I have not put virus protection software on the new system yet and I prefer not to. I only need windows to work offline with software I have hard copies of. I just want to know what I can get away with. I've had no issues with Linux but countless issues when using Windows. Some Windows system problems I've experienced were caused by the antivirus software itself.

Comment: If you do not mount the Windows partitions, you should be pretty safe of accidental damage to your Windows installation (unless you mess up the partitions, of course). Ubuntu can access your Windows' NTFS partitions, but it won't do that unless you mount them or configure them to mount automatically. I also don't think there is any noteworthy threat by malware targeting at Ubuntu that search for Windows partitions specifically.

Comment: Have you considered removing the hdd from the laptop while booting linux? It's what I've done in the past during installations, to prevent any damage to the hdd. It'll keep you safe, but might be a bit of a hassle

Comment: Thank you. I'll do a deep dive into setting my partition up properly to be sure it's right. I forget that someone actually needs to target my weakness. Not a lot of hackers looking for a system running Linux with a Windows portion on the drive.

Comment: Personally, I would be very hesitant to use Windows without anti-virus protection. Since your Windows system will have to go online to obtain security updates anyway it would seem less than ideal. Ubuntu is highly unlikely to infect your unmounted Windows installation, just as Windows is highly unlikely to infect your unmounted Ubuntu installation, but after 30 years, I cannot in clear conscience recommend a lack of antivirus software under Windows whether you intentionally connect to the internet with it or not.

Comment: Brndn2k I have not. I try hard to be a Linux guy but I still have to reasurch most things like how to run without the hdd. I would think some bios settings might need to be tweaked. This is a good idea since I would only use the method occasionally when needed. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you elder geek what you say is fact. My intention is to use this system to interface with Plc Programable logic controllers, a commercial arduino for anyone whose not familiar. I probably won't update the 7 pro if I don't have to. I haven't had a Windows system in 8 years if you have a recommendation for antivirus that's low maintenance.